# Container bridge networking with subnet on Hetzner and CNI

Tags: networking, linux-networking, containers, hetzner

I am trying to create a private network of VMs and containers on [Hetzner Cloud](https://www.hetzner.com/cloud). I've tested this setup on my local home network and all works fine.

The plan is to have a private network for the VMs (`10.0.0.0/8` just for testing). For my test I am using `10.10.0.1` and `10.10.0.2` as VMs. And each VM, will have a CNI bridge network, (eg: `172.20.0.0/16`, for container). I want to make the bridge networks accesible by any VM on the `10.0.0.0/8` network, with static routes.

On Hetzner, I've configured a static route `172.20.0.0/16 to 10.10.0.1`. On `10.10.0.1` I have a CNI bridge network for Podman, configured on the same range `172.20.0.0/16`.

Any container that gets placed on that network, has no trouble pinging or reaching out to: local, other containers, host or internet, and the host (`10.10.0.1`) has no trouble reaching the containers (`172.20.0.X`).

The problem is when I want to ping the container from `10.10.0.2`. I've monitored traffic with `tcpdump` and `iftop`, and the Hetzner route seems to work just fine, as connections reach the VM on `10.10.0.1` (`ens10`). Which makes me wonder if it's a routing issue between the `ens10` and `podman-vlan` bridge interfaces?

Here are the routes from `10.10.0.1`

```
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src X.Y.Z.W metric 100 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10 
10.0.0.1 dev ens10 scope link 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.20.0.0/16 dev podman-vlan proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src X.Y.Z.W metric 100
```

On the `10.10.0.2` VM, I've only done a `ip r add 172.20.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1` (which seems to work as).

My expectation was to get `10.10.0.2 -> 10.0.0.1 -> 10.10.0.1 -> 172.20.0.1 -> 172.20.0.X`. Instead everything seems to get lost at `10.10.0.1`, including if I try `ping -I ens10 172.20.0.X`

This is the CNI config:

```
{
  "cniVersion": "0.4.0",
  "name": "podman",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "type": "bridge",
      "bridge": "podman-vlan",
      "isGateway": true,
      "ipMasq": true,
      "promiscMode": true,
      "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "routes": [{ "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }],
        "ranges": [
          [
            {
              "subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
              "gateway": "172.20.0.1"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "portmap",
      "capabilities": {
        "portMappings": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "firewall"
    },
    {
      "type": "tuning"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with Docker existing on that VM and iptables.

Checking `iptables -L` on the VM

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
CNI-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Docker took priority. So either configure the rule to forward the right interface to CNI/Podman/Docker, or whatever is needed.

In my case, removing Docker was an option and that fixed everything.